# Adding hover to a grid ( that look like table)

Tags: grid, hover

Im trying to add hover to my grid.
I literally manage to do so for every single cell including the whole div, but when im trying to do for the whole row nothing happens! (IGNORE please the colorful rows at the start)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous"> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 text-lg-start text-start text-sm-right text-md-start col-sm-12 col-md-6  col-lg-3">Make</div>
        <div class="col-12 text-lg-center text-center text-sm-center text-md-center col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">Things</div>
        <div class="col-12 text-lg-center text-center text-sm-center text-md- center col-sm-6 col-md-6  col-lg-3">Go</div>
        <div class="col-12 text-lg-end text-end text-sm-end col-sm-6 col-md-6 text-md-end col-lg-3 ">Right</div>
    </div>
    
</div>
</div>

<div class="container"> 
    
    <div class="row">
            <div id="dif" class="col">animal</div>
            <div id="dif" class="col">price</div>
            <div id="dif" class="col">image</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="td" class="col">kitten</div>
        <div id="td" class="col">70$</div>
        <div id="td" class="col">             <img src="https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bootstrapbaymisc/blog/24_days_bootstrap/sheep-3.jpg" class="img-fluid img-circle " class="rounded" alt="Sheep"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="td" class="col">puppy</div>
        <div id="td" class="col">80$</div>
        <div id="td" class="col">             <img src="https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bootstrapbaymisc/blog/24_days_bootstrap/sheep-3.jpg" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" alt="Sheep"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="td" class="col">bunny</div>
        <div id="td" class="col">30$</div>
        <div id="td" class="col">             <img src="https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bootstrapbaymisc/blog/24_days_bootstrap/sheep-3.jpg" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" alt="Sheep"></div>
    </div>



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.row > div {
    height: 50px;
    font-size: x-large;
    text-align: center;

}

.row > div:nth-child(1) {
    background: red
}

.row > div:nth-child(2) {
    background: yellow
}

.row > div:nth-child(3) {
    background: blue
}

.row > div:nth-child(4) {
    background: purple
}

#dif {
    background:white;
    font-weight: 900;
    border: solid black 1px;
     height: 150px;
}

#td {
    height: 150px;
    background:white;
    border: solid black 1px;
    margin: 0px;


}

.row {
   margin: 0px
}

.row:hover{background-color:gray;}

img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    
}
```

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the following code and the rows will highlight in grey:

```
.row > div:nth-child(1) {
    background: red
}

.row > div:nth-child(2) {
    background: yellow
}

.row > div:nth-child(3) {
    background: blue
}

.row > div:nth-child(4) {
    background: purple
}
```

Remove `background:white;` from

```
#td {
    height: 150px;
    background:white;
    border: solid black 1px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: yap, it did the work. can you please explain what was the problem in the first place? when i need to have hover on something i cant have a color for the background?

Comment: It has to do with [CSS specificity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp). The other elements had styles that took precedence over the hover style. You can have hover and a background color, but I'm not 100% sure what you're looking for. Try targeting `.row` instead of `#td` for a non-hover background color.

Comment: It was only for practice, tried to make over on the cells while the do have a background color that is not white, red, or any color else